# Boostrap validator: why space-only values do not show errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using bootstrap validator for the form validation.

If the value of input are just spaces it doesn't show errors even though input is `required`.

E.g `name` field in example gets validating when hitting `space` couple of times, `twitter` has a pattern so doesn't allow space-only values).

http://jsbin.com/roxasen/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine.

You have just forgotten to include bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <div class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-inline row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.js"></script>
  
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not about boostrap though, but about the validation. Try hitting a couple of spaces in the first field, it doesn't show error even though field is technically blank.

Comment: like `twitter`, you can check for regex for name as well like `pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$"` . I have updated my answer

Comment: There is a problem though – it only accepts English characters. Is it possible to make it multilingual?